# Bulk upload string columns as VARCHAR to Amazon Redshift

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

#### Is it possible to pass VARCHARS to an SQL DB (AWS Redshift) instead of Strings in bulk without creating the table on my own?

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'actually_a_string': "Super_Long_String_Even_Longer_Than_256_Characters"}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I want to bulk upload it to AWS Redshift. 
Problem is: they only allow Strings to have characters < 256.

So when I bulk upload it with:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import psycopg2
engine = sa.create_engine('postgres://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[URL]/[PORT]/[DB_NAME]'
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='test', if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

It gives me the following error: 
*(psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(256)* 

Redshift actually allows VARCHARS to be huge, like 60k characters or so.

Is it possible to tell postgres to pass VARCHARS instead of Strings somehow?
My table is huge so I really don't want to create it on my own and define all columns etc.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using the `dtype=` argument of `.to_sql()` to declare a specific type/length for the column(s) involved?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a table with a very large number of columns in Redshift?  materialization is not free.  Also, just in case your table is *really* huge, note there is a 1600 column limit, although you will likely run into other internal limits before you get to the point of querying that many columns.  Finally, note `varchar` lengths in RS are bytes, not characters, and you may have multi-byte characters.

Comment: Hey @MaxGanzII,
it is not that huge. It's like 100 columns, some of them are json format which is the reason they are longer than 256 characters. Actually it is the order table of shopify. Maybe there is a solution for json columns? Because uploading dictionaries is also not possible. So what you say is, I have to pass variables like b'Super_Long_String' and it should work?

Comment: I mean when you define in DDL a `varchar`, the size you give is the maximum size in *bytes*, not characters.  So a `varchar(10)` gives you ten bytes to play with - not ten *characters*,  In UTF-8, there are only 127 characters which use one byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to bulk upload it

```
orders.to_sql(con=engine, 
dtype={col_name: sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR (length=60000) for col_name in orders}, 
name='orders_shopify_de', if_exists='replace', index=False, method='multi')
```

With this it's working, although defining a hardcoded length for every column is not the best solution. 
So case closed. Thank you for your help. :)